# Objective-C Facebook video sharing for the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios7

I'm very much new to objective-c. Basically, all I see is black right now. I'm assigned to code the facebook sharing part of the app we're making, and believe me, I've tried almost all tutorials (none worked, I've tried) and went through the questions here in stack, and I still couldn't upload. So please, someone help?

How to upload videos to facebook via the app? Please provide sample code if you have.

Here is the code I'm trying right now:

```
-(void)post
{
    NSURL *videourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos"];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Here's to the Crazy Ones" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *pathURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSLog(@"PATH: %@", filePath);

    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"title": @"uploading",
                             @"description": @"testing..."
                             };

    NSLog(@"uploading...");

    SLRequest *uploadRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                  requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                            URL:videourl
                                                     parameters:params];
    [uploadRequest addMultipartData:videoData
                           withName:@"source"
                               type:@"video/quicktime"
                           filename:[pathURL absoluteString]];
    NSLog(@"Here it goes...");
    uploadRequest.account = self.facebookAccount;
    NSLog(@"Past uploadrequest...");
    [FBSession setActiveSession:FBSession.activeSession];
    [uploadRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       // [FBSession setActiveSession:FBSession.activeSession];
        if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
         //   [FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI: YES];
            [FBSession setActiveSession:FBSession.activeSession];
        }

        NSLog(@"response string: %@", responseString);
        NSLog(@"Here I am...");
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }else
            NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
    }];
}
```

With this I'm getting an error of:

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I provide a link which will guide you step step to upload video to FB [**Tutorial**](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/)

Comment: Is that for the latest version of FacebookSDK?

Comment: Can I use two versions of the SDK at once if I'm going to use that tutorial?